# Why my wordpress plugins don't load the javascript code in order to let me use them?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to develop my own theme and i've run in the following issue:

I use WP-RECIPE and I can't use the button "print recipe", but if I install other theme that button is working. So I thought it's because of the plugin, so I installed something random like 'social share', same output. What's wrong?

[PRINT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGCBx.png)

This is my functions.php for styles and scripts:

```
    <?php
//JAVASCRIPT SI CSS

function pezona_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'layout',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/layout.css',
        array(),
        false,
        'all'
    );
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'stil',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/stil.css',
        array(),
        false,
        'all'
    );
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'stil-responsive',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/stil-responsive.css',
        array(),
        false,
        'all'
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pezona_enqueue_styles' );

function pezona_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'main-js',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/javascript/lazysizes.min.js',
        array(),
        '1.0.0',
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pezona_enqueue_scripts' );

?>
```

Any ideea guys? thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is. Are your scripts printed in the HTML? What do you mean with *can't use*? Does the console show any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Where to check that? or how, well if i change my theme with other template i can use the button "print recipe", (this button opens a new tab and generate the content to be ready for print ), or the pinterest button if you press it you can share my article.

Comment: You can check if your scripts and styles are in the HTML by examining the HTML with your browser inspector or right click in your page and click *view source*. If the functions.php script works properly, then your styles and script should be present in the HTML. You can identify them by their `id` attributes, which values should be `layout-css`, `stil-css`, `stil-css-response` and `main-js-js`. As for the print button, open the developer console in your browser and check for errors.

Comment: thanks man! javascript was loaded, interaction didn't happen because of my z-index value, have a nice day